# react.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jsx, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I have a basic problem with SSR in Laravel, Inertia and React. Problem because I have only in SSR mode and I don't have this problem in dev & CSR modes.

I use Laravel-inertia-react-vite

Home.jsx:

```
import {usePage} from "@inertiajs/react";
import MasterLayout from "@/Layouts/MasterLayout";
import CourseCard from "@/Components/CourseCard";

export default function Home(props){
    const courses = usePage().props.courses;
 return(
        <>
 <MasterLayout >
 <CourseCard courses={courses.slice(0,2)}/>
</MasterLayout />
</>
)
```

now in CourseCard.jsx:

```
export default function CourseCard(props) {
    const { courses } = props;
    return (
        <>
            <div className="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-3 css-1h77wgb">
                {courses.map(({ id, title, slug, poster, description, status, price, type, time, has_favorited }) => (
                {/*others code*/}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

course data:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{id: 5, user_id: 1, type: 'payment', title: 'React.js', category: 'javascript', …}
1
: 
{id: 3, user_id: 1, type: 'payment', title: 'python', category: 'python', …}
2
: 
{id: 2, user_id: 1, type: 'vip', title: 'PHP', category: 'php', …}
3
: 
{id: 1, user_id: 1, type: 'payment', title: 'php Advanced', category: 'python', …}
length
: 
4
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

I have this error

```
react.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

when I delete the courses and SSR work. and I think the problem is with my data. But I don't know.